# Shall I use "I'm" or "This is" in this case?

Tags: word-choice

I'm editing my personal blog and I added a picture of myself, and under it I'd like to write a short introduction about myself.

I'm starting it with "*Hello, this is yzT, a Computer Engineer specialized in Information Security*". But I'm wondering whether ***this is*** is properly used there, or if it would be better to write ***I'm yzT***.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a general rule we use 'this is' only when introducing ourselves on the telephone.

In this case you should say, "I'm yzT" otherwise it appears that some unknown person is writing about you.